# $M_n(k)\otimes_kB\cong M_n(B)$, where $k$ is a field, and $B$ is a $k$-algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, algebras

> Let $k$ be a field and let $B$ be a $k$-algebra, then $M_n(k)\otimes_kB\cong M_n(B)$.

There is no need to read the following texts.

---

A brief overview of what I know, and what I did:

Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrice with 1 in the entry $ij^{\rm th}$, and $0$ elsewhere. Then $E_{ij}$'s form a basis for $M_n(k)$. $M_n(k)\otimes_kB$ is a free $B$-module, with the generating set $\{E_{ij}\otimes1_B\}$. Also we have these relations: $(E_{ij}\otimes1_B)(E_{kl}\otimes1_B)=\delta_k^j(E_{il}\otimes1_B)$. I can not go further, and even I can not recognize if I am walking in a suitable direction or not.

I solved some exercises on tensor products, most of them are solved with the same idea for this problem: Let $G$ be an abelian group, such that the order of any element is finite. Then $G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}\cong0$. But that problem has a different nature, and I stuck in that problem, and I don't know how should I show that.

---

Final Edit: (My solution to $M_n(A)\otimes_kB\cong M_n(A\otimes B)$, where $k$ is a field, and $A$ and $B$ is a $k$-algebras.) (I am not sure if my solution is true or not)

$M_n(A)\otimes_kB$ is a free $B$-module, with the basis $\{(E_{ij}\otimes1_B) \mid 1 \leq i, j \leq n \}$. Now define the map $\varphi$ on the elements of basis as follows:

\begin{gather*}
\varphi:M_n(A) \otimes_k B \longrightarrow M_n(A\otimes B)\\
(E_{ij}\otimes1_B) \mapsto E_{ij}
\end{gather*}

Then we have

$$\varphi((E_{ij}\otimes1_B)(E_{kl}\otimes1_B))=\varphi(E_{ij}E_{kl}\otimes 1_B)=\varphi(\delta_k^jE_{il}\otimes 1_B)=\delta_k^jE_{il}=E_{ij}E_{kl}=\varphi(E_{ij}\otimes1_B)\varphi(E_{kl}\otimes1_B)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $k$-modules, $M_n(k)$ is isomorphic to $k^{(n^2)}$, and similarly, $M_n(B) \sim B^{(n^2)}$. Therefore, since tensor product distributes over direct sum, $M_n(k) \otimes_k B \sim M_n(B)$ as $k$-modules. The isomorphism is given via $(x_1, ... x_{n^2}) \otimes b \rightarrow (b x_1 , ... b x_{n^2})$. Call this function $\phi$.

The only thing we need to do now is to show that this preserves multiplication. By the distributive  property, it suffices to show that it preserves multiplication on pure tensors.

Let $A, B \in M_n(k), x, y \in B$. Then, $\phi(A \otimes x * B \otimes y) = \phi(AB \otimes xy) = xy AB$, and $\phi(A \otimes x) * \phi(B \otimes y) = xA * yB = xy AB$.

Therefore, it preserves multiplication and is an isomorphism.

Comment: I read your answer, but I had difficulties to realize it. (1)The function $\phi$ is defined between some arrays of length $n$, but $k^{(n^2)}$, and $B^{(n^2)}$ are some arrays of length $n^2$. (2) Why if $\phi$ preserves multiplication, then it gives us an isomorphism?

Comment: @NeoTheComputer the first one was a typo. For the second one, $\phi$ is an isomorphism of $k$-modules, so it's a bijection of sets, and also preserves addition. Therefore, we just need to check that it preserves multiplication.

Comment: Let me point out that your map is the same of my answer, but you've wisely rilied on the distributivity property of direct sum and tensor product.

Comment: @DavidLui Why your multiplication is coincidence with the usual matrix multiplication? I think your map does not care about the algebraic structure, and that proves only an isomorphism between somethings a little bit reacher than the sets.

Comment: @NeoTheComputer By definition of multiplication in a tensor product of rings, $A \otimes  x * B \otimes y = AB \otimes xy$, and $xA * yB$ is multiplication in $M_n(B)$. Note that $B$ is used for both the ring and the matrix, but there should be no confusion as they can be told apart by context.

Comment: @DavidLui (1): Yes, you are right, I agree with you. (2): Clearly, it is surjective, and by comparing the dimensions it follows that it is injective. Am I concluding in the right way? (3): Also, I think your proof is working for a more general problem: $M_n(A)\otimes_kB\cong M_n(A\otimes B)$, where $k$ is a field, and $A$ and $B$ are $k$-algebras. Am I right?

Comment: It's not a dimension counting argument. For the more general problem, I think so, but I haven't checked.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments the approch is wrong but I still think it is a bit valuable so I'm not deleting it for now.

I'll try. $B$ is a $k$-algebra hence there exists a ring homorphism $T:k\rightarrow B$ such that $T(k)$ is in the center of $B$. Given a matrix $M \in M_n(k)$ let me extend the notation naming $T(M) \in M_n(B)$ the matrix obtained applying $T$ elementwise.

Consider the following map
\begin{gather*}
\phi:M_n(k) \otimes_kB \longrightarrow M_n(B)\\
\phi(M \otimes b) = b \ T(M)
\end{gather*}

The map such defined is a $k$-module homomorphism. Considering that the elements $E_{ij}\otimes b$ are mapped into the elements $bE_{ij}$ of $M_n(B)$ we can conclude that the map is surjective.

Now suppose two elements have the same image, so

\begin{gather*}
\phi(M_1 \otimes b_1) = \phi(M_2 \otimes b_2) \\
b_1 T(M_1) = b_2 T(M_2)
\end{gather*}

This means

\begin{gather*}
\forall(i,j) \ \ m_{ij}^1 b_1 = m_{ij}^2 b_2 \\
\forall(i,j) \ \ b_2 = (m_{ij}^2)^{-1}m^1_{ij} b_1 \\
\end{gather*}

So for each $(i,j)$ the ratio $r=(m_{ij}^2)^{-1}m^1_{ij}$ is constant, and we have $b_2 = rb_1$, so

\begin{gather*}
M_2 \otimes b_2 = M_2 \otimes rb_1 = rM_2 \otimes b_1 = M_1 \otimes b_1
\end{gather*}

demonstrating that $\phi$ is an injection on simple tensor.

Comment: That just proves injectivity on pure tensors.

Comment: Suppose that ${\rm Ann}(b_1)$ has an element $r' \in k$, ie there is $r' \in k$ such that $r'b_1=0$. Then $(r+r')b_1=rb_1+r'b_1=b_2$, and the ratios $r=(m_{ij}^2)^{-1}m^1_{ij}$ are not necessarily equal. Also even if your proof was correct, then it just shows that the kernel does not contains pure tensors (simple tensors) and does not contatins sum of two pure tensors.

Comment: I forgot to assume the condition $0\neq r'$.

Comment: You're right guys, i'll keep thinking on it to see if the proof can ben be fixed.

Comment: But if the others step of demonstration are correct and the statement is true, this will not implies that in that particular case every tensor is simple? I'll try to prove it as soon as I can.