# Difficulty with understanding and computing tensor products.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebras

I have a serious misunderstanding of tensor products. I think If I can understand these two examples, then most of the difficulties will be eliminated.

$0^{\rm th}$ Question (Edited): Let $k$ be a field, and let $A$ and $B$ and $C$ be finite-dimensional $k$-algebras. To prove that $A \otimes B \cong C$, is it sufficient to give a multiplication-preserving bijection between the elements of basis as a $k$-vector-space, or as a $B$-module?

---

First and main question: Let $K/k$ be a Galois extension of fields, with the Galois group $G$. Then $K\otimes_k K \cong K^G$, $x\otimes y \mapsto \Big(\sigma(x)y\Big)_{\sigma \in G}$.

Let's call that map by $\varphi$, then it is easy to see that

$$\varphi((x\otimes 1)(x'\otimes 1))=\varphi(xx'\otimes 1)=\Big(\sigma(xx')\Big)_{\sigma \in G}=\Big(\sigma(x)\Big)_{\sigma \in G}\Big(\sigma(x')\Big)_{\sigma \in G}=\varphi(x\otimes 1)\varphi(x'\otimes 1)$$

---

Why didn't we defined the map as follows? $K\otimes_k K \cong K^G$, $x\otimes y \mapsto \Big(xy\Big)_{\sigma \in G}$

Let's call that map by $\varphi_{\rm id}$, then again we have

$$\varphi_{\rm id}((x\otimes 1)(x'\otimes 1))=\varphi_{\rm id}(xx'\otimes 1)=\Big(xx'\Big)_{\sigma \in G}=\Big(x\Big)_{\sigma \in G}\Big(x'\Big)_{\sigma \in G}=\varphi_{\rm id}(x\otimes 1)\varphi_{\rm id}(x'\otimes 1)$$

What is wrong with them in this situation?

---

Or why didn't we defined the map as follows? Fix $\tau \in G$, then $K\otimes_k K \cong K^G$, $x\otimes y \mapsto \Big(\tau(x)y\Big)_{\sigma \in G}$

Let's call that map by $\varphi_{\tau}$, then again we have

$$\varphi_{\tau}((x\otimes 1)(x'\otimes 1))=\varphi_{\tau}(xx'\otimes 1)=\Big(\tau(xx')\Big)_{\sigma \in G}=\Big(\tau(x)\Big)_{\sigma \in G}\Big(\tau(x')\Big)_{\sigma \in G}=\varphi_{\tau}(x\otimes 1)\varphi_{\tau}(x'\otimes 1)$$

What is wrong with them in this situation?

---

---

---

Second question: I asked another question before here: [$M_n(k)\otimes_kB\cong M_n(B)$, where $k$ is a field, and $B$ is a $k$-algebra.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853686/m-nk-otimes-kb-cong-m-nb-where-k-is-a-field-and-b-is-a-k-algebra)

Let $k$ be a field, and $A$ and $B$ be $k$-algebras. Then $M_n(A)\otimes_kB\cong M_n(A\otimes B$). (I am not sure if my solution is true or not)

$M_n(A)\otimes_kB$ is a free $B$-module, with the basis $\{(E_{ij}\otimes1_B) \mid 1 \leq i, j \leq n \}$. Now define the map $\varphi$ on the elements of basis as follows:

\begin{gather*}
\varphi:M_n(A) \otimes_k B \longrightarrow M_n(A\otimes B)\\
(E_{ij}\otimes1_B) \mapsto E_{ij}
\end{gather*}

Then we have

$$\varphi((E_{ij}\otimes1_B)(E_{kl}\otimes1_B))=\varphi(E_{ij}E_{kl}\otimes 1_B)=\varphi(\delta_k^jE_{il}\otimes 1_B)=\delta_k^jE_{il}=E_{ij}E_{kl}=\varphi(E_{ij}\otimes1_B)\varphi(E_{kl}\otimes1_B)$$

Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $K\otimes_kK\to K^G$ defined by $x\otimes y\mapsto(xy)_{\sigma\in G}$ is not an isomorphism
(as long as $|K:k|\ge2$). Every element $x\otimes1-1\otimes x$ lies in its kernel,
and that element is nonzero if $x\in K\setminus k$.

Comment: By considering your explanations, now it is clear to me that the 2nd and the 3rd map are not suitable to show the isomorphism $K\otimes_k K \cong K^G$. But yet I have a difficulty to understand why the first map gives us an isomorphism?$$\varphi((x\otimes 1)(x'\otimes 1))=\varphi(xx'\otimes 1)=\Big(\sigma(xx')\Big)_{\sigma \in G}=\Big(\sigma(x)\Big)_{\sigma \in G}\Big(\sigma(x')\Big)_{\sigma \in G}=\varphi(x\otimes 1)\varphi(x'\otimes 1)$$This relation shows that $\varphi$ is a multiplication preserving map between basis of two $K$-module of rank $|G|$. (Isn't it?) And why this is sufficent?

Comment: $0^{\rm th}$ Question: Let $k$ be a field, and let $A$ and $B$ and $C$ be finite-dimensional $k$-algebras. To prove that $A \otimes B \cong C$, is it sufficient to give a multiplication-preserving bijection between the elements of basis as a $k$-vector-spaces, or as a $B$-modules?

Comment: @Neo: yes, it suffices to give a multiplication -(and-unit)-preserving bijection on some basis. What $B$-module structure do you have in mind on $C$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you so much. $B \cong 1\otimes B \rightarrow A \otimes B$, so I can conclude that $A\otimes B$ has a $B$-module structure. You are right about $C$; in some problems I can find an easy $B$-module structures, but in some others I can't. Let's call the "multiplication —(and-unit)— preserving bijection on some basis" by the "star property checking". Does the sufficiency of the "star property checking" holds for both of the $k$-vector spaces and $B$-module structures? or it holds for just one of them? I think it holds for both of them.

Comment: @NeoTheComputer: once you've written down a $k$-algebra isomorphism, $C$ acquires a $B$-module structure given by right multiplication. Different choices of isomorphism give different such structures, and if you've just picked some other arbitrary $B$-module structure on $C$ you're not guaranteed that it arises from an isomorphism to $A \otimes_k B$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you so much for your fruitfull and enlightening helps.